# How to remove the child when removing the parent?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ngselect

I am making angular application with angular dynamic form where i am using [ng-select library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select).

The **HTML** with select:

```
    <div *ngFor="let question of questions" class="form-row {{question.class}}">
            <ng-container *ngIf="question.children">
                <div [formArrayName]="question.key" class="w-100">
                    <div *ngFor="let item of form.get(question.key).controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i" class="row mt-1">
                        <div *ngFor="let item of question.children" class="{{item.class}} align-middle">
                            <div class="w-100">
                                <dynamic-form-builder [question]="item" [index]="i" [form]="form.get(question.key).at(i)"></dynamic-form-builder>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-label-group" *ngIf="showTemplateDropdown">
                                    <ngi-select placeholder="Select Template" [required]="true" [hideSelected]="false" [multiple]="true" [items]="templateList"
                                     dropdownPosition="down" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id" (add)="getTemplateValues($event)" (remove)="onRemove($event)">
                                    </ngi-select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6">

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-right">
                                <div class="btn-group  float-right">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-round btn-fab mat-raised-button" mat-min-fab="" mat-raised-button="" type="button"
                                     (click)="addControls('template_properties')">
                                        <span class="mat-button-wrapper"><i class="material-icons mt-2">add</i></span>
                                        <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div>
                                        <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
                                    </button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-round btn-fab mat-raised-button" mat-min-fab="" mat-raised-button="" type="button"
                                     (click)="removeControls('template_properties')">
                                        <span class="mat-button-wrapper"><i class="material-icons mt-2">remove</i></span>
                                        <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div>
                                        <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="!question.children">
                <div class="w-100">
                    <dynamic-form-builder [question]="question" [form]="form"></dynamic-form-builder>
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
```

Here the `[items]="templateList"` has the following,

```
[{"id":"5bebba2c20ccc52871509d56","name":"Template One"},
{"id":"5bebba5720ccc52871509d57","name":"Template Two"},
{"id":"5bebba8d20ccc52871509d5d","name":"Template Three"}]
```

I am having `(change)="getTemplateValues($event)"` event for detecting each change happen when we select an item from dropdown.

The change event function **Edited**,

```
    getTemplateValues(e) {
      this.dynamicFormService.getRest("url" + '/' + e.id").subscribe(res => {
  try {
    if (res.status === "true") {
      res.data.template_properties.forEach(element => {
        this.templateArray.push(element);
      });
      this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
      for (let i = 0; i < this.templateArray.length; i++) {
        this.addControls('template_properties');
      }
      let propertiesArray = [];
      this.templateArray.forEach(element => {
        propertiesArray.push(element);
      });
      this.form.patchValue({
        'template_properties': propertiesArray
      });
    } else {

    }
  }
  catch (error) {

  }
})
```

}

`console.log(this.propertiesArray)` gives the following,

```
[{"property_name":"Property one","property_type":4,"property_required":true,"property_origin":1},{"property_name":"Property one","property_type":5,"property_required":true,"property_origin":1}]
```

In the below image i have deleted template three but the template three properties still showing in it..

[image]

Here first i am filtering the data first and ignoring the duplicates and each time i am sending the newly selected values alone to the service and fetching the data related to the id `element.id`.

And using `this.addControls('template_properties')` to make open the number of rows, and elements will get patched to the form `template_properties`.

```
this.form.patchValue({
 'template_properties': propertiesArray
});
```

As of now everything working fine..

The **problem actually arise from here**:

If we delete a selected list from dropdown, (say i have selected all three template and i have **deleted** the `template two` then that particular `template`'s `template_properties` needs to get deleted..

I have **tried** with `(remove)="onRemove($event)"` but its not working because while remove data, the `(change)` function also calls..

How can i remove the `template_properties` with `this.removeControls('template_properties');` of particular deleted template name in the change event or remove event..

**Remove Function**:

```
  onRemove(e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.dynamicFormService.getRest("url" + '/' + e.value.id").subscribe(res => {
      try {
        if (res.status === "true") {
          for (let i = 0; i < res.data.template_properties.length; i++) {
            this.removeControls('template_properties');
          }
        } else {

        }
      }
      catch (error) {

      }
    })
  }
```

**Remove Control**:

```
  removeControls(control: string) {
    let array = this.form.get(control) as FormArray;
    console.log(array)
    array.removeAt(array.length);
  }
```

`console.log(array)` gives,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty easy fix. Use `(add)` instead of `(change)` in `ngi-select`.

```
 onRemove(e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.dynamicFormService.getRest("url" + '/' + e.value.id").subscribe(res => {
      try {
        if (res.status === "true") {
          this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);

          // Issue is here, you should remove only specific record
          // which is being passed from function `e`
          for (let i = 0; i < res.data.template_properties.length; i++) {
            this.removeControls('template_properties'); 
          }

          let propertiesArray = [];
          this.templateArray.forEach(element => {
            propertiesArray.push(element);
          });
          this.form.patchValue({
            'template_properties': propertiesArray
          });
        } else {

        }
      }
      catch (error) {

      }
    })
  }
```

Pass the index in `removeControls`  where you want to remove the element from.

```
  removeControls(control: string, index:number) {
    let array = this.form.get(control) as FormArray;
    console.log(array)
    array.removeAt(index);
  }
```

`console.log(array)` gives,
[image]

Comment: If i use like this, then in remove the entire ```template_properties``` is getting removed..

Comment: It means, the logic of `onRemove` function is wrong. Share the code of `onRemove`.

Comment: Kindly see my updated code for remove.. If i am wrong kindly make me correct for remove function.. How to remove the removed item's (template name) ```template_properties```..

Comment: Sunil, Also updated my getTemplateValues (add) function by removing the filter which shows error after implementing ```(add)``` .. Even now Its working for add but not for remove.. Kindly check whether ```removeControl('template_properties')``` is right one please..

Comment: Updated the answer where could be the issue. Share your `removeControls` code as well.

Comment: Updated with removecontrol function at last in my question.. If any needed i can provide the code.. Kindly help me to fix it..

Comment: Also if i give ```this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.questions);
``` this line inside onRemove function, then the entire data is getting removed.. (I hope its not needed in remove function)

Comment: Updated my remove function again (minimized).. Now its getting removed as per the count in that template if template one has one template_properties length then it gets deleted one at last, same way the template three has two properties and it deletes the last two properties instead of the two properties which is in the middle.. Say i have choosen template one,three,two and so three is in middle so the middle two properties (as three has two properties) needs to get removed but the last two (one from template three and one from template two is getting deleted..

Comment: Share html code where you have` <ngi-select placeholder="Select Template" [required]="true" [hideSelected]="false" [multiple]="true" [items]="templateList" dropdownPosition="down" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id" (change)="getTemplateValues($event)" (remove)="onRemove($event)"> </ngi-select`

Comment: I have give complete HTML that i use.. It may not be clear for you.. It was derived from this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-rrfv1b

Comment: you need to pass the `index` from `removeControls`. Updated the answer. Note : You may need to pass this index from html and `onRemove` function.

Comment: Do you mean to add like ```(remove)="onRemove($event,index)"```??

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: It gives the following, ```{"index":2,"label":"Template Three","value":{"id":"5bebba8d20ccc52871509d5d","name":"Template Three"},"htmlId":"ab33bc17cd61","selected":false}
``` When i delete the template three..

Comment: and print the value of `array` index in `removeControls` function.

Comment: Sorry are you asking to do ```console.log(array)``` inside removecontrol function??

Comment: yes, for this line `let array = this.form.get(control) as FormArray;`

Comment: If i am using, I have tried with ```for (let i = 0; i < res.data.template_properties.length; i++) {
            this.removeControls('template_properties', e.index); 
          }```..
As ```console.log(e)``` has index value as i given you in previous comment.. It deletes correctly when we delete from last but if we delete from center only one item getting deleted and not the count the index has.. But deleting from last to first works..

Comment: Sorry ignore my edit in your solution.. I have given screenshot of data comes from array in my question..

Comment: Sunil, Whether this is a right approach, ```this.removeControls('template_properties', e.index);``` all the time its not helping to delete the right element??